# R foreach in the function can not recognize list

Tags: r

I am trying to use parallel computing in R, but I got some trouble.

First, I generate a list which consists of species and time as following

```
df <- data.frame(species = rep(c(1:100), each = 100), time = runif(10000,150, 1008))
species <- unique(df$species)
```

Then I run the following code to get a sort of sum of step-functions

```
#standard
ntw <- function(now){
  L2 <- 0
  for (Ii in species){
    time <- subset(df, subset = species == Ii)$time
    time <- sort(time)
    L2 <- L2 + stepfun(time,seq(0,length(time)))(now)
    
  }
  return(L2)
}
```

Try

```
> ntw(152)
[1] 27
```

So far so good, now I load the doParallel and try to duplicate the same thing using parallel computing:

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
#parallel
nt <- function(now){
  L2 <- 0
  foreach(i = species,.combine = rbind) %dopar% {
    time <- subset(df, subset = species ==i)$time
    time <- sort(time)
    L2 <- L2 + stepfun(time,seq(0,length(time)))(now)
  }
  return(L2)
}
```

Try

```
> nt(152)
Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find 'df'"
```

don't understand what's going on.

## ------------------

Update:
Following advices by @chinsoon12 and @brittenb, I specify the export with the following code

```
#parallel
nt <- function(now){
  L2 <- 0
  foreach(i = species,.combine = rbind,.export = "df") %dopar% {
    time <- subset(df, subset = species ==i)$time
    time <- sort(time)
    L2 <- L2 + stepfun(time,seq(0,length(time)))(now)
  }
  return(L2)
}
```

Now try

```
> nt(152)
[1] 0
```

which is inconsistent with the standard one. Any idea ?

Comment: You would have to export df and species to each cluster

Comment: Thanks @chinsoon12 , but can you be more specific? I am quite now to doParallel

Comment: The parallel functions will only automatically "export" the variables and functions within its current scope. So you have to tell it that you want `species` exported to the new R sessions so that it can use it. Look at the help pages for `foreach` and read up on how to export variables, functions, and packages.

Comment: Thanks @brittenb, I update the code, and specify the export, but I got a wrong result. Any thought ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the return value of the `foreach`, which in your case is an array build by `rbind`ing the result of each call to `stepfun`:

```
nt <- function(now){
        result <- foreach(i = species,.combine = "rbind", .export = "df") %dopar% {
                time <- subset(df, subset = species ==i)$time
                time <- sort(time)
                stepfun(time,seq(0,length(time)))(now)
        }
        return(sum(result))
}

nt(152)
[1] 28
```

A big mistake here is trying to assign values to L2 in parallel : You're trying to assign several values at the same time by different process but to the same variable...

Also you can rewrite this a bit simpler using the `"+"` combiner:

```
nt <- function(now){
        foreach(i = species,.combine = "+", .export = "df") %dopar% {
                time <- subset(df, subset = species ==i)$time
                time <- sort(time)
                stepfun(time,seq(0,length(time)))(now)
        }
}

nt(152)
[1] 28
```

(*) For better reproducibility always include `set.seed(xxx)` when using randomness